i can't run "npm run build" due dependency conflict between webpack & optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin
I would like to build the assets files (src folder) in the dist folder which contains the html files using Webpack.
this is the structure of the project:
-dist/
-index.html

... other html files
-src/
-css/
-img/
-js/
-lib/
-scss/

Here is package.json:
{
  "name": "milky.local",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/js/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack serve --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.3",
    "@wordpress/dependency-extraction-webpack-plugin": "^5.6.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^12.0.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.8.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack": "^5.91.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^5.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.3",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.1"
  }
}
    

webpack.config.js:
/**
 * Webpack configuration.
 */

const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');


const JS_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'js');
const IMG_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'img');
const LIB_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib');
const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');

const entry = {
    main: path.join(JS_DIR, 'src/js/main.js'), // Fix path concatenation
};

const output = {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
};

const plugins = (argv) => [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({
        cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: ['**/*'], // Clean all files before each build
        cleanStaleWebpackAssets: 'production' === argv.mode,
    }),

    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: 'css/[name].css',
    }),

    new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [
            { from: LIB_DIR, to: path.join(BUILD_DIR, 'lib') },
        ],
    }),
    new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
        cssProcessor: require('cssnano'),
        cssProcessorOptions: {
          preset: ['default', { discardComments: { removeAll: true } }],
        },
        canPrint: true
      }),


];

const rules = [
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: [JS_DIR],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
    },
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            'css-loader',
            'sass-loader',
        ],
    },
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            'css-loader',
        ],
    },
    {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|svg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
        use: {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: '[path][name].[ext]',
                publicPath: 'production' === process.env.NODE_ENV ? '../' : '../../',
            },
        },
    },
    {
        test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
        exclude: [IMG_DIR, /node_modules/],
        use: {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: '[path][name].[ext]',
                publicPath: 'production' === process.env.NODE_ENV ? '../' : '../../',
            },
        },
    },
];

module.exports = (env, argv) => ({
    entry: entry,
    output: output,
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        rules: rules,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                // Other babel options...
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
                cssProcessor: cssnano,
            }),
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                cache: false,
                parallel: true,
                sourceMap: false,
            }),
            new CssMinimizerPlugin(),

        ],
    },
    plugins: plugins(argv),
    externals: {
        jquery: 'jQuery',
    },
    plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin()],

});    

Error :
vagrant@homestead:/var/www/milky.local$ npm i
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: milky.local@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: webpack@5.91.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   webpack@"^5.91.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@2.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!   uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@"^2.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2024-04-05T12_42_37_605Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2024-04-05T12_42_37_605Z-debug-0.log
vagrant@homestead:/var/www/milky.local$ npm run build

milky.local@1.0.0 build
webpack --mode production

sh: 1: webpack: not found
i tried to downgrade the version of the packages and the error still presists
